# C# .NET Get Scale Weight USB Windows 7 64 Bit

Tags: c#, usb, hid

I have a Mettler Toledo PS60 scale.  I am trying to write an extremely simple .NET console application that works on my Windows 7 64 Bit machine that allows me to get the current weight off the scale.

I am using the HidLibrary here: 
https://github.com/mikeobrien/HidLibrary

I am using this basic code to actually talk to the scale here: https://github.com/nricciar/usb_scale

On my Vista 32 bit machine with USB, everything is working great.  It is just on my 64 Bit Windows 7 machine, the application hangs on the Read() method.

Anyone have any thoughts on what might be happening in regards to why my 64 bit machine might be causing trouble?  Anyone think I may be going about this wrong anyway?

Comment: My first thought is the HidLibrary was compiled as a x86 file. I see that x64 support was only added in Jan 2011 have you tried to target the dll itself to x64 only?  it also might be the driver for the device itself that is the problem.  One would need to invesigate your application is being run within the WoW environment or not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have compiled the HidLibrary as x64 and my console app is also built against x64.  Same result.