# USB HID hangs on Read() in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, usb, hid

I am trying to connect to a USB digital scale. The code does connect to the scale as `scale.IsConnected` comes true, but it hangs on `scale.Read(250)` where 250 should be the timeout in milliseconds, but it never return from Read.

I am using the code from [this thread](https://github.com/mikeobrien/HidLibrary/issues/17) except one change which was due to the new version of [Mike O Brien's HID Library](https://github.com/mikeobrien/HidLibrary):

```
public HidDevice[] GetDevices ()
{
    HidDevice[] hidDeviceList;
            
    // Metler Toledo
    hidDeviceList = HidDevices.Enumerate(0x0eb8).ToArray();
    if (hidDeviceList.Length > 0)
        return hidDeviceList;
    
    return hidDeviceList;
}
```

---

I managed to get the scale working, take a look at Mike's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596531/c-sharp-net-get-scale-weight-usb-windows-7-64-bit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get the scale working. In my callback, which runs when *scale* returns data, I was doing `Read` which is a blocking call.

So a deadlock was created, and I should have only used `ReadReport` or `Read`. Take a look at Mike's example below which he posted [here](https://github.com/mikeobrien/HidLibrary/issues/17).

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using HidLibrary;

namespace MagtekCardReader
{
    class Program
    {
        private const int VendorId = 0x0801;
        private const int ProductId = 0x0002;

        private static HidDevice _device;

        static void Main()
        {
            _device = HidDevices.Enumerate(VendorId, ProductId).FirstOrDefault();

            if (_device != null)
            {
                _device.OpenDevice();

                _device.Inserted += DeviceAttachedHandler;
                _device.Removed += DeviceRemovedHandler;

                _device.MonitorDeviceEvents = true;

                _device.ReadReport(OnReport);

                Console.WriteLine("Reader found, press any key to exit.");
                Console.ReadKey();

                _device.CloseDevice();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not find reader.");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        private static void OnReport(HidReport report)
        {
            if (!_device.IsConnected) {
                return;
            }

            var cardData = new Data(report.Data);

            Console.WriteLine(!cardData.Error ? Encoding.ASCII.GetString(cardData.CardData) : cardData.ErrorMessage);

            _device.ReadReport(OnReport);
        }

        private static void DeviceAttachedHandler()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Device attached.");
            _device.ReadReport(OnReport);
        }

        private static void DeviceRemovedHandler()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Device removed.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `Data` class where you create an instance of it inside the method OnReport?

Comment: This is all the code needed i believe. been a while though

Answer (score 2):

I cannot help you with your problem, but a while ago I had to integrate a foot switch into an application and I found this USB HID C# library that worked perfectly:

*[A USB HID Component for C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18099/A-USB-HID-Component-for-C)*

Maybe you should give it a try because it is very simple to integrate.